# Creating a summary row for each group in a dataframe based on other variables in the group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Fairly new to R, ended up in the following situation: I want to create a summary row for each group in the dataframe based on `Year` and `Model`, where a `value` of each row would be based on the subtraction of `value` of one `Variable` from others in the group.

```
df <- data.frame(Model = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
             Year = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2030, 2030, 2030, 2040, 2040, 2040),
             Variable = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "E", "A", "C", "D"),
             value = c(15, 2, 5, 25, 6, 4, 4, 41, 24,1, 15, 3, 2))
```

I have managed to create a new row for each group, so it already has a `Year` and a `Variable` name that I manually specified using:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(Model, Year) %>% group_modify(~ add_row(., Variable = "New", .before=0))
```

However, I am struggling to create an equation from which I want to calculate the `value`.

**What I want to have instead of NAs:** `value` of A-B-D in each group

*Would appreciate any help. My first thread here, pardon for any inconvenience.*

Comment: What does A-B-D mean? A minus B minus D?

Comment: You don't have `B` and `D` in all of your groups. How do you want to deal with missingness?

Comment: @TarJae Yes, exactly!

Comment: @r2evans then missing values ideally should be treated as 0 (there are `A` 's in every group so then the desired value would be equal to A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pivot wide and then back; this would add rows with zeros where missing:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Variable, values_from = value, values_fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(new = A - B - D) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Model, Year), names_to = "Variable")


# A tibble: 24 × 4
   Model  Year Variable value
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
 1     1  2020 A           15   
 2     1  2020 B            2
 3     1  2020 C            5
 4     1  2020 D            0
 5     1  2020 E            0
 6     1  2020 new         13    # 15 - 2 - 0 = 13
 7     2  2020 A           25
 8     2  2020 B            6
 9     2  2020 C            4
10     2  2020 D            4
# … with 14 more rows
```

EDIT - variation where we leave the missing values and use `coalesce(x, 0)` to allow subtraction to treat NA's as zeroes. The `pivot_wider` creates NA's in the missing spots, but we can exclude these in the `pivot_longer` using `values_drop_na = TRUE`.

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Variable, values_from = value) %>%
  mutate(new = A - coalesce(B,0) - coalesce(D,0)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Model, Year), names_to = "Variable", values_drop_na = TRUE)

# A tibble: 17 × 4
   Model  Year Variable value
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
 1     1  2020 A           15
 2     1  2020 B            2
 3     1  2020 C            5
 4     1  2020 new         13
 5     2  2020 A           25
 6     2  2020 B            6
 7     2  2020 C            4
 8     2  2020 D            4
 9     2  2020 new         15
10     2  2030 A           41
11     2  2030 C           24
12     2  2030 E            1
13     2  2030 new         41
14     2  2040 A           15
15     2  2040 C            3
16     2  2040 D            2
17     2  2040 new         13
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I needed, thank you! Is there a way to do this without introducing these new rows with zeros where missing?

Comment: Edited to add this.